# Not able to get value of dropdownlist.selectedvalue on SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, postback, selectedvalue, selectedindexchanged

After much much research I cannot find the same problem anywhere, under my circumstances. I've enabled viewstate at the page, control, and individual dropdown levels. Page_Load only loads the dropdown if PostBack true according to code.

The problem is that on postback (triggered by the DropDownList or any control), "Empty Parameter" shows in my debugging label, which tells me it's not grabbing the SelectedValue from the dropdown in its selectedIndexChanged method. Also, my dropdowns reset to their initial value before the PageLoad "PopulateFilterDropdowns" method.

Any ideas? I've been searching here, google, anywhere and everywhere I can go. Everybody's problem is usually a lack of "IsPostback" or EnableViewState="true", but no dice on my end. I will mention this is a ascx UserControl, inside of a page with a MasterPage. But I believe the code of each of those is irrelevant to this problem, and quite large to post here.

Help!?

Dropdown:

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTopics" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTopics_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Topic" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

Page_Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            PopulateFilterDropdowns();
        }

    }
```

Following methods:

```
public void PopulateFilterDropdowns()
    {
        PopulateTopicDropdown();
        PopulateAssetTypeDropdown();
        PopulateLevelDropdown();
    }
public void PopulateTopicDropdown()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XXX"].ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("StoredProc", conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        //ListItem itm = new ListItem();
                        //itm.Value = rdr[0].ToString();
                        //itm.Text = rdr[0].ToString();
                        ddlTopics.Items.Add(new ListItem(rdr[0].ToString(), rdr[0].ToString()));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Problem zone:

```
 protected void ddlTopics_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddlTopics1 = (DropDownList)sender;
        string topic = ddlTopics1.SelectedValue;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(topic))
            lblDebug.Text = "Empty Parameter";
        else
            lblDebug.Text = topic;
        //PopulateRecordsByTopic(topic);
    }
    public void PopulateRecordsByTopic(string topic)
    {
        //Query and Binding of repeater on page
    }
```

Comment: This looks like disabled ViewState (sorry to say that). You can check if it is actually enabled: (1) Add a Label to the form, with some initial text set in markup; (2) In `Page_Load`, inside `if (!IsPostBack)`, change the Label's text; (3) Check the displayed text after a postback (e.g. after changing the `ddlTopics` selected item). If the Label's text reverts to its initial text, the ViewState is disabled.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the first line and replace "ddlTopics1" with "ddlTopics" in the subsequent lines?

Comment: @ConnorsFan if viewstate were disabled wouldn't the label fail to change to "Empty Parameter"? and it would just at it's initial value on every PostBack right?

Comment: @PradeepKumar Same behavior happens, whether I parse "sender" as ddl, or just call ddlTopics from the go, it just doesn't grab the value.

Comment: The new Label's text will be displayed after you set it in code-behind. It is on the next postback that you can tell, yes, as long as that postback does not set the text again. If you have another button in your page, you can click it to cause a postback and see what happens.

Comment: By the way, after the first postback caused by the item selection, does the list contain only the first item? If the other items are still there, then the ViewState is probably enabled.

Comment: @ConnorsFan It does not get set after all the postbacks, it retains it's value, and gets set with all the postbacks after to the correct value.

The list contains the first item that loads with the page before being populated on Page_Load -> IsPostback

I know it seems as a disabled viewstate, but how do you explain the debug label's behaviour, and the fact that I've set it to true in like 50 different spots.

Comment: If the `EnableViewState` property is set to `false` at the page level, setting it to `true` for individual controls has no effect. Similarly, if the ViewState is disabled in Web.config, enabling it at the page level or at the control level will have no effect.